# Have a dedicated UIViewController for each RootElement in MonoTouch.Dialog?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

It's easy to create a multi-level menu structure using nested `RootElements` in `MonoTouch.Dialog` but how would you go about having a specific `UIViewController` manage each root instead?  The reason I want each `RootElement` to have it's own `UIViewController` is because I want to be able to easily control things like background image and toggling the NavigationBar from screen to screen and doing so is trival from within a `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
public RootElement (string caption, Func<RootElement, UIViewController> createOnSelected)
```

which let you create the `UIViewController` (e.g. a `DialogViewController` that you customized or a type that inherit from it).

This will let you keep nesting your `Element` while giving most of the control over the view and it's controller.

**UPDATE**

Here's how this can be used:

First declare your method that will create the UIViewController. The method signature must match `Func<RootElement, UIViewController>`, e.g.

```
    static UIViewController CreateFromRoot (RootElement element)
    {
        return new DialogViewController (element);
    }
```

Next create your root elements using:

```
    var root_element = new RootElement ("caption", CreateFromRoot);
```

The above will give you the same as:

```
    var root_element = new RootElement ("caption");
```

except you're now able to customize the `DialogViewController` to your liking before returning it.

Comment: What does the code for createOnSelected look like?  Also, you have "public" in there, do you mean "new"?

Comment: No, what's above is the constructor declaration (from MonoTouch.Dialog) that you should use in your code (by doing a new). I'll update answer to show this.

Answer (score 8):

Same thing, less methods...

```
    var root_element = new RootElement("caption", (RootElement e) => {
        return new DialogViewController (e);
    });
```