# MonoTouch.Dialog load elements on the fly

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, xamarin

What is the recommended approach when I need to load elements on the fly?

My app has one particular element which should have a disclosure accessory and when clicked/entered it should go to a new section with elements which I retrieve from a webservice.

Should I add an onclick delegate which loads and adds the elements and navigates to the section or is there some other approach more suitable?

Comment: or should I have a delegate on the sub section that triggers on initialize or load or similar?

Comment: Ah! got it!

Solved with the help of these responses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545466/have-a-dedicated-uiviewcontroller-for-each-rootelement-in-monotouch-dialog?rq=1